# filling a dataframe or matrix with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, dataframe

Is there a quick way to fill this matrix `df` with the values of `n1` then `n2` and finally `n3` in order from left to right?

```
df=matrix(, nrow = 3, ncol =3)
rownames(df)<- c("1","2","3")
colnames(df)<- c("A", "B", "C")
n1= seq(1:3)
n2= seq(6:8)
n3= seq(10:12)
```

Comment: `df[] <- cbind(n1, n2, n3)`? (Also, I don't think that `seq(6:8)` does what you think it does....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of columns to `cbind`, one way would be:

```
df[] <- do.call(cbind,mget(ls(pattern="n\\d+"))) #here I am assuming that all the objects created follow the pattern `n1`, `n2`, `n3` etc.

df
#  A B  C
#1 1 6 10
#2 2 7 11
#3 3 8 12
```

If you are filling a `data.frame` such as `df1`

```
 df1[] <- mget(ls(pattern="n\\d+"))
 df1
 #  A B  C
 #1 1 6 10
 #2 2 7 11
 #3 3 8 12
```

#### data

```
 df <- matrix(, nrow = 3, ncol =3)
 rownames(df)<- c("1","2","3")
 colnames(df)<- c("A", "B", "C")

 df1 <- as.data.frame(df)
 n1 <- 1:3
 n2 <- 6:8
 n3 <- 10:12
```